# Python Partition By

Tags: python, group-by, timestamp, partition

I have the below dataframe df:

```
| Staff_ID | Join_Date | Time_Stamp |
|----------|-----------|------------|
| 1        | 3/29/2016 | 4/23/2016  |
| 1        | 3/29/2016 | 3/29/2016  |
| 1        | 3/29/2016 | 6/21/2016  |
| 2        | 5/15/2016 | 4/1/2016   |
| 2        | 5/15/2016 | 5/25/2016  |
| 3        | 7/24/2016 | 6/21/2016  |
| 3        | 7/24/2016 | 6/10/2016  |
| 3        | 7/24/2016 | 4/21/2016  |
```

I want to get the Min and Max "Time_Stamp Date" partition by "Staff_ID" such that the resultant dataframe is as follows:

```
| Staff_ID | Join_Date | Time_Stamp | Min_Time_Stamp | Max_Time_Stamp |
|----------|-----------|------------|----------------|----------------|
| 1        | 3/29/2016 | 4/23/2016  | 3/29/2016      | 6/21/2016      |
| 1        | 3/29/2016 | 3/29/2016  | 3/29/2016      | 6/21/2016      |
| 1        | 3/29/2016 | 6/21/2016  | 3/29/2016      | 6/21/2016      |
| 2        | 5/15/2016 | 4/1/2016   | 4/1/2016       | 5/25/2016      |
| 2        | 5/15/2016 | 5/25/2016  | 4/1/2016       | 5/25/2016      |
| 3        | 7/24/2016 | 6/21/2016  | 4/21/2016      | 6/21/2016      |
| 3        | 7/24/2016 | 6/10/2016  | 4/21/2016      | 6/21/2016      |
| 3        | 7/24/2016 | 4/21/2016  | 4/21/2016      | 6/21/2016      |
```

How can I do this in Python ?

Comment: I have not used any code...I already have df. I need to write some python code to convert df into the resultant dataframe as described above

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `groupby` with `transform` and `assign`:

```
g = df.groupby('Staff_ID')['Time_Stamp']
df.assign(Min_Time_Stamp = g.transform(min), Max_Time_Stamp = g.transform(max))
```

Output:

```
     Staff_ID    Join_Date    Time_Stamp Max_Time_Stamp Min_Time_Stamp
1   1           3/29/2016    4/23/2016      6/21/2016      3/29/2016  
2   1           3/29/2016    3/29/2016      6/21/2016      3/29/2016  
3   1           3/29/2016    6/21/2016      6/21/2016      3/29/2016  
4   2           5/15/2016    4/1/2016       5/25/2016      4/1/2016   
5   2           5/15/2016    5/25/2016      5/25/2016      4/1/2016   
6   3           7/24/2016    6/21/2016      6/21/2016      4/21/2016  
7   3           7/24/2016    6/10/2016      6/21/2016      4/21/2016  
8   3           7/24/2016    4/21/2016      6/21/2016      4/21/2016
```

### Timings:

@CarlesMitjans method:

> 10 loops, best of 3: 33.3 ms per loop

@ScottBoston method:

> 100 loops, best of 3: 5.52 ms per loop

Comment: @Symphony Did either of these answers help you?  If so, would you please [upvote and accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) an answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` and then merge the results:

```
group = df.groupby("Staff_ID", as_index=False)["Time_Stamp"]
df = pd.merge(df, group.min(), on=["Staff_ID"])
df = df.rename(columns = {"Time_Stamp_x" : "Time_Stamp", "Time_Stamp_y": "Min_Time_Stamp"})
df = pd.merge(df, group.max(), on=["Staff_ID"])
df = df.rename(columns = {"Time_Stamp_x" : "Time_Stamp", "Time_Stamp_y" : "Max_Time_Stamp"})
```

Result:

```
   Join_Date  Staff_ID Time_Stamp Min_Time_Stamp Max_Time_Stamp
0  3/29/2016         1  4/23/2016      3/29/2016      6/21/2016
1  3/29/2016         1  3/29/2016      3/29/2016      6/21/2016
2  3/29/2016         1  6/21/2016      3/29/2016      6/21/2016
3  5/15/2016         2   4/1/2016       4/1/2016      5/25/2016
4  5/15/2016         2  5/25/2016       4/1/2016      5/25/2016
5  7/24/2016         3  6/21/2016      4/21/2016      6/21/2016
6  7/24/2016         3  6/10/2016      4/21/2016      6/21/2016
7  7/24/2016         3  4/21/2016      4/21/2016      6/21/2016
```